# Check option before submit from modal

Tags: jquery

I have a form on a page, however, there's no submit. There's a link that launched a modal dialog using colorbox plugin. Submit button is actually in that dialog. In order for me to submit the form I use delegate() because submit button is not added to DOM, until the modal is launched.

I added a checkbox that must be checked before the form can be submitted, but I think I'm missing something because I can't submit regardless whether it is checked or not.

Here's my code

**JS**

```
$('#openModal').colorbox({ 
    html: 'some text <input type="checkbox" name="chk" id="chk"><input id="mySubmit" type="button" value="submit form">' 
});

$('#mySubmit').click(function() {

    if ($('#chk').is(':checked')) {
        $('#myForm').submit();
    } else {
        alert('Must check first...');
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
    <div id="openModal">open modal</div>

</form>
```

What am I missing?

UPDATE:
Had a missing ID... dah. Thanks @McMaster for catching it. Added id...

Comment: is your click function working at all?  You aren't delegating but it might still work if you are binding it after you create your element

Comment: your call to your check box is wrong (doubt it will fix anything), but this is how you should call it `$('input[name="chk"]')` or give your check box an `id` which it currently does not have..

Comment: @McMaster You're right! Embarrassing... Afternoon caffeine deprivation syndrome. :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are not delegating your click event in this case.

Try this

```
$('body').delegate('click' ,'#mySubmit' ,function() {

    if ($('#chk').is(':checked')) {
        $('#myForm').submit();
    } else {
        alert('Must check first...');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are dynamically adding the `input` element that is used in the colorbox. Note the change from `name` to `id`.

```
$('#openModal').colorbox({
    html: '<input type="checkbox" id="chk" /><input id="mySubmit" type="button" value="...">';
});
```

Thus you should use `on`.

```
$('#mySubmit').on("click", function() {
    if ($('#chk').is(':checked')) {
        $('#myForm').submit();
    } else {
        alert('Must check first...');
    }
});
```